# Search commits by message with Github GraphQL API?

Tags: api, github, graphql

I'm trying to use Github GraphQL API to search commits by message. In Github REST API, I just need to send POST request to `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=examplemsg&sort=committer-date`, but in GraphQL API, I cannot find how I can do this.

I tried to use `search` query, but enum `SearchType` has only 3 types, `ISSUE`, `REPOSITORY`, and `USER`. Is it possible to find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is **not possible** to search commits by Github GraphQL API, it has not been supported yet. You will need use REST API instead.

Answer (score -1):

**GitHub GraphQL API**

[Dev GraphQL link](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/)

Github Account login

> GitHub's GraphQL Explorer

```
{
  viewer {
    login
    bio
    location
    isBountyHunter
  }
  viewer {
    login
    starredRepositories {
      totalCount
    }
    repositories(first: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          stargazers {
            totalCount
          }
          forks {
            totalCount
          }
          watchers {
            totalCount
          }
          issues(states: [OPEN]) {
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> The response from our API might be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "login": "webmasters964",
      "bio": "",
      "location": "New Delhi",
      "isBountyHunter": false,
      "starredRepositories": {
        "totalCount": 4
      },
      "repositories": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "WCFRESTfulService",
              "stargazers": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "forks": {
                "totalCount": 1
              },
              "watchers": {
                "totalCount": 1
              },
              "issues": {
                "totalCount": 0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "Running-Node.js-server",
              "stargazers": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "forks": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "watchers": {
                "totalCount": 1
              },
              "issues": {
                "totalCount": 0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "Running-JavaScript-Files",
              "stargazers": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "forks": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "watchers": {
                "totalCount": 1
              },
              "issues": {
                "totalCount": 0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "Express.js-in-simple",
              "stargazers": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "forks": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "watchers": {
                "totalCount": 1
              },
              "issues": {
                "totalCount": 0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "angularquickstart",
              "stargazers": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "forks": {
                "totalCount": 0
              },
              "watchers": {
                "totalCount": 1
              },
              "issues": {
                "totalCount": 0
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]